# Subscribe to events

Tags: c#, event-binding

There are two options for subscribing to events:

1. `this.button1.click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click)`
2. `this.button1.click += this.button1_click`

What are the advantages and disadvantages of both techniques?

Answer (score 1):

The second one is easier to read ;-) - they both work in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Second option is only syntactic sugar for the first one.

You can check generated IL-code and you'll see that compiler generates exactly the same IL-code for both cases.

Answer (score 1):

The second option is preferred by many - including ReSharper - because it is easier to read and less code. The generated IL code however is the same, so it is purely a question of preference.